# JavaScript .style.webkitFilter can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, css, filter

i'm quite frustrated right now so i decided to ask on stackoverflow. I can't get elements to blur according to mouse movement. I have a simple js code:

```
/*
vars
*/
var world = document.getElementById( 'world' ),
    viewport = document.getElementById( 'viewport' ),
    worldelement = document.getElementsByClassName( 'elementbase' ),
    worldXAngle = 0,
    worldYAngle = 0,
    d = 0;

/*
   czyta ruchy myszka i zapisuje
*/
window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function( e ) {
    worldYAngle = -( .5 - ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) ) * 90;
    worldXAngle = ( .5 - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) ) * 90;
    worldblur = Math.abs(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 10;
    updateView();
} );

/* sobie tam zmenia katy na rotate */
function updateView() {
    world.style.transform = 'translateZ( ' + d + 'px ) \
        rotateX( ' + worldXAngle + 'deg) \
        rotateY( ' + worldYAngle + 'deg)';
    for (var i = 0; i < worldelement.length; i++) {
        worldelement[i].style.webkitFilter = 'blur(' + worldblur +' px)';
        worldelement[i].style.transform = 'translateZ( ' + d + 'px ) \
        rotateY( ' + -worldYAngle + 'deg) \
        rotateX( ' + -worldXAngle + 'deg)';

    }
}
```

i've created

```
worldblur = Math.abs(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 10;
```

which gives me the number i want and tried to put this number here:

```
worldelement[i].style.webkitFilter = 'blur(' + worldblur +' px)';
```

but its not working, but when i write static number for example 'blur(10px)'; its working.

I'm quite new to javascript, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm getting frustrated because rotateX and rotateY are working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space before the `px`. Removing it should make it work. (PS: you are on a WebKit browser?)

Comment: yes im using webkit, 

and your answer is the correct one ! i'm ashamed that i forgot about spaces :D

thank you very much :)

Comment: @UrbanMaciej No worries, it's easy to trip up on CSS units in JavaScript :)